# How does Google Compute Recommend Memory Upgrades on vms

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Often Google Compute recommends upgrading cpu/memory of the vms I am using.  I can see the cpu graph of the instance so I can imagine where it gets the idea I should upgrade the CPU, but there is no such thing for ram so How does it know when to upgrade the ram?

Comment: Why did you just delete your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153533/nodejs-require-that-pauses-execution/43153638#43153638) that I had just answered?  My reward for taking the time to answer your question and explain how you would do what you want to do is that you just delete the question?  That's not how Stack Overflow is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the companion [Google Stackdriver](http://www.stackdriver.com/) app which by default collects more metrics for all your instances. The URL for the metrics for a single instance is

```
https://app.google.stackdriver.com/instances/<INSTANCE_ID>?project=<PROJECT_ID>
```

Answer (score 1):

The hypervisor gives us some idea of the number of RAM pages that have been used, and we can make a recommendation based on that. However, since in any case Google does not inspect the RAM, we don't actually know what the purpose of pages are, merely how many are backed by physical RAM. Installing the StackDriver agent allows us to get better information from the guest OS about what is considered to be in use by the OS, and we can actually recommend better discounts in that case. The docs page [1] talks about this a little, although it could probably go into more detail about the memory usage signals.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-sizing-recommendations-for-instances